# Error in starting Wildfly 8.0 server with JDK 1.8

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I get this error when I start the server. I tried everything but still not sure what the cause is . Please help

Thanks

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE"
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:119)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:338)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:291)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:300)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:542)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:97)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:300)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:262)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:438)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:117)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\standalone\log\boot.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:154)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.setFile(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:105)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:192)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.<init>(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:73)
    ... 22 more
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 3):

The main error is this one:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\standalone\log\boot.log

Check that the file exists and/or there are no permission restrictions which might stop Java from creating that file.

The final line in your question:

> 22 more Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Seems to suggest that WildFly 8.0 is not Java 8 certified. That is, it was not designed to run on Java 8 so, while there is every likelihood that it will start under Java 8, there may be some unexpected behaviour.

I would recommend that, if possible, you either upgrade your WildFly to the latest stable release (8.2 as of this date) or if that isn't possible, downgrade your Java version to 7.

Comment: Thanks for reply

I tried to create a patch file (boot.log) but again the error came as "Access denied"
How to pinpoint the access restriction issue ?

Comment: That's a windows issue, really, but you might try this...(1) right click the top level WildFly folder (2) click the security tab (3) select your user (which runs WildFly) (4) Click Advanced (5) select your user in the new window (6) click "change permissions" (7) select your user + click "edit" (8) make sure all read/write permissions are allowed, click OK (9), tick "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions......" box (10) click apply (11) click OK on all open windows and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows 10?

[Similar issue with windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824853/error-starting-wildfly-10-0-0-final/36953717#36953717)

If so, try starting the server through the Command Prompt (admin) rather than just normal cmd.

To access this, just right click Start and you will see it.

Thanks,
Ben